# Is it possible/advisable to register a MS CRM plugin WITHOUT using the registration tool provided by microsoft

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

Basically I am looking at doing remote deployment of custom plugin and workflow to an IFD MS CRM deployment.  This means that the tool provided by Microsoft cannot be used.

Does anyone do this?

Is it advisable or not?

What resources are available?

I've done a lot of google-ing and reading and it seems like everyone is using the deployment tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. There are a series of entities that you need to set up to do this. If I'm not mistaken, the SDK includes the source for a plugin registration tool... you can look at that to see how it's done, and you'd just need to update it to work with IFD.